# Building With Docker Returns HashSum Errors

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Whenever I try to build with Docker, I'm encountering HashSum errors:

> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/main/p/postgis/postgis-doc_2.5.2+dfsg-1~exp1.pgdg90+1_all.deb
>   Hash Sum mismatch    Hashes of expected file:
>       - SHA256:8b04987f50d0a76c1bf8a830ea7f184e9a562892b9f835ab01cad576135fcc21
>       - SHA1:68dcdd364b906882659a6dfd03f0db4bc7f2f385 [weak]
>       - MD5Sum:f13452c5f91078db1df409fa531ac888 [weak]
>       - Filesize:3742202 [weak]

This occurs for several Postgres files and one of the Postgis files.

I've tried running apt-clean/apt-update, removing lists and adding a file to handle a bad-proxy from [this issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/543).

Has anyone encountered/found a solution to this? Dockerfile in question is below.

```
FROM postgres:9.4

RUN sed -i 's|http://httpredir.debian.org/debian|http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian/|g' /etc/apt/sources.list

ADD /99fixbadproxy ./badproxy 
RUN apt-get install apt && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    postgis \
    postgresql-9.4-postgis-scripts \
    postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.2 \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Have you tried with a newest postgres image?

Comment: yes, the result is the same